# Concave for positives, convex for negative?

Tags: calculus, functions

I'm looking for a function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with properties:

1. continuous,
2. strictly increasing,
3. unbounded,
4. strictly concave for positive numbers, and
5. strictly convex for negative numbers.

For instance, the function $$f(x)=\frac{\exp(x)}{1+\exp(x)}$$ satisfies 1, 2, 4, and 5, but not 3 as it is bounded by the unit interval.

Comment: What about $f(x)=-x^3$ ?

Comment: @javi: strictly increasing

Comment: How about $\text{sign}(x)x^2$ or will that get the concavity / convexity backwards?

Comment: @mathreadler It will :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the cube root function, or $\operatorname{sgn}(x) \sqrt{|x|}$ ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}$

Comment: That answer has already been given.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x) = x+\arctan x$ is a real analytic example.